# Is there a way to serilize specific attributes of object using annotations in modal in .net (like Groups annotation in symfony)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

In Symfony, there is a way to serialize specific attributes of object using annotations in the model, this annotation is called Groups
you can see the documentation here
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#component-serializer-attributes-groups-annotations

Example

```
     class Person
{
         * @Groups({"group1", "group2"})
        public $firstname;
    
         * @Groups("group2")
        public $lastname;
}
```

so when we serilize and noralze data with

```
  $data = $serializer->normalize($PersonObject, null, ['groups' => 'group1']);
```

The return will be just $firstname, but if we change group1 to group2 it gonna be $firstname and $lastname

I want to implement the same idea using annotations in .net classes and serialize specific attributes with groups,

Is there a way to do that in .net/C#?

Answer (score 1):

Json.NET allows conditional property serialization via a ShouldSerialize{PropertyName}() method that you add to your class.

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/conditionalproperties.htm#ShouldSerialize

You might be able to adapt this for your purposes. e.g. You could create a new PropertyAttribute to define the groups a property belongs too.   Then, before serialization, set which matching groups you want to serialize in the object, by populating a new List GroupsToMatch property.   Then in the ShouldSerialize method for each property, return true if the GroupToMatch list matches the PropertyAttribute's groups.

Example code https://dotnetfiddle.net/cKDhaw

Comment: Thank you for ur solution, I know it may take too long to make an example but could u make the same example I gave with this json.net solution?

Comment: Because I'm such a nice guy I've done a quick example for you https://dotnetfiddle.net/cKDhaw

Comment: @Akrem I took time to do a code example for you the other day   I was wondering if it helped you with your question?

Comment: Thank you for your time 
Actually, your solutions work for simple class attributes, but when it comes relation attribute or a collection attribute I don't know yet 
I mean if an attribute is   

    [Group(new string[] { "group2" })]
   public Person p { get; set; }
it should serilize all attribute of person class where group is "group2"
Also when it comes to 
public ICollection<Person> p { get; set; }
it should return it should serilize all attribute of person class where group is "group2" of all collection .